# Unable to get proxyaddress using Get-ADUser from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I have the following code that I call from a web page which keeps returning an empty object.  I run other powershell cmdlets from a similar procedure (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=Staff,OU=All Users, DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx') which works fine and gives me a list of the organizational units, so I know that the page can execute the powershell ok, but for some reason I am having problems getting a list of the proxyaddresses.  Completely stuck as I don't know how to retrieve the proxyaddresses.

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks
Darren

```
   Public Function GetProxyAddresses(sUsername As String, sIPAddress As String) As StringBuilder
        Try
            Dim psConfig As RunspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create
            Dim psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConfig)
            psRunSpace.Open()

            Using psPipeline As Pipeline = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline

                psPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-ADUser " + sUsername + " -properties proxyaddresses | select-object @{""name""=""proxyaddresses"";""expression""={$_.proxyaddresses}}")

                Try
                    Dim builder = New StringBuilder
                    Dim results = psPipeline.Invoke()

                    For Each PSObject In results
                        builder.Append(PSObject.Properties("proxyAddresses").Value + "\n")
                    Next

                    GetProxyAddresses = builder

                End Try
            End Using
            psRunSpace.Close()

        Catch ex As System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException
            AddLogEntry(ex.Message, "N/A", ex.ErrorCode, Now.Date, sUsername, sIPAddress, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of ways to achieve this.  I have given the following ways to fulfill your requirement. Hope this satisfies your need.

```
# sample Examples as CSV

Get-ADUser MyUser01 -properties * | select-object name, samaccountname, surname, enabled, @{"name"="proxyaddresses";"expression"={$_.proxyaddresses}} | Export-Csv ProxyAddress.csv

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=TestOU,dc=domain,dc=com' -Properties proxyaddresses | select name, @{L='ProxyAddress_1'; E={$_.proxyaddresses[0]}}, @{L='ProxyAddress_2';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[1]}} | Export-Csv ProxyAddress.csv –NoTypeInformation

# Will find any active directory object that has an exact match to the e-mail address you place in the filter ie. email@yourdomain.com  

Get-ADObject -Properties mail, proxyAddresses -Filter {mail -eq "email@yourdomain.com" -or proxyAddresses -eq "smtp:email@yourdomain.com"}

# This filter (Using wildcards) will also grab not only smtp addresses but other types such as x500: eum: sip: etc.

Get-ADObject -Properties mail, proxyAddresses -Filter {mail -like "*emailportion*" -or proxyAddresses -like "*emailportion*"}

# Using a LDAP query to find the matching object
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(|(mail=email@yourdomain.com)(proxyAddresses=smtp:email@yourdomain.com))"

# LDAP with wildcards

Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(|(mail=*emailportion*)(proxyAddresses=*emailportion*))"

# Using SIP 

Get-ADObject -Properties proxyAddresses -Filter {proxyAddresses -eq "sip:email@yourdomain.com"}
```

Comment: Thanks Ranadip.  I will give some of these a go.

Comment: @DarrenM: sure. Enjoy Coding